# Why does my nav items appear in the dropdown menu when my screen is full width?

Tags: html, css

My navbar menu should only show the toggle dropdown feature in the mobile view, however, it's showing the toggle dropdown view in fullscreen and the links are not positioned where they need to be. I'm quite confused as to why
I have a picture of how it is and one with where the links should be appearing

[image: How it appears]

[image: How it should be]

Here is my code

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top py-3">
                <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Illustrious Marketing</a><button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger dropdown-toggle"  role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                            <div class=" nav-item dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Become a Seller</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Become a Buyer</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Cart
                                <svg class="bi bi-bucket" width="1.20em" height="1.5em" viewBox="-2 5 18 10" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.5A4.5 4.5 0 003.5 6h-1a5.5 5.5 0 1111 0h-1A4.5 4.5 0 008 1.5z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.61 5.687A.5.5 0 012 5.5h12a.5.5 0 01.488.608l-1.826 8.217a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.464 1.175H4.802a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.464-1.175L1.512 6.108a.5.5 0 01.098-.42zm1.013.813l1.691 7.608a.5.5 0 00.488.392h6.396a.5.5 0 00.488-.392l1.69-7.608H2.624z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                                </svg>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use Media Queries Please.https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove `navbar-toggler-right` from the button class so it looks like this

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
```

and give it another go?

This tends to cause problems. If it works, let me know what you're trying to achieve, you might be better off using flex or even other bootstrap calls.